# Regex that will match a combination of letters and numbers NOT ending with "km"

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm new here so I'll try my best.

I have a line of text containing different car information.

> 65101km,Sedan,Manual,18131A,FWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,camry,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010

I am trying to write a regex that will match a combination of letters and numbers NOT ending with "km" in that line.
It is the car's serial number that can differ from one carmaker to another.
For example:

> 18FO724A, 18131A, 19BF723A

These are different serial numbers from different car models.

I tried this:

```
/((?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[^km]$|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9])/
```

But it keeps on returning the # of kilometers

> 65101km

while the answer I need is

> 18131A

Any help will do.
Thanks

Comment: What is the logic behind `18131A`, and why is that your expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to return all the delimited values (in between `,`) except the ones that shows the km?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's the car's serial number

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs no just the one word with letters and numbers not ending with 'km'

Comment: You need to provide _logic_ by which we can figure out how to extract the car's serial number.  Currently, you have not done this.

Comment: Here's the issue: your serial number is just a bunch of numbers and letters - same thing that every other one of your delimited values have. There is currently no logic that can separate your serial numbers from a normal word like 'Sedan'. Some appropriate logic would be "All serial numbers will always start with at least 2 digits (minimum) and always end in a capital letter that is between A-F, and will always be between 5-8 characters long" would be a good place to start.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs but the serial number is the only thing in my text that contains both letters and numbers other than the number of kilometers (ends with km). Thanks

Comment: Sara, I think both you and @K.Dᴀᴠɪs have valid points. However, you should consider the possibility that the contents of the string may change in future to include a data item that meets your test for a serial number but in fact is not one. Incidentally, "But it keeps on returning the # of kilometers." brought a smile to my face. You run the code. The answer is not what you expect, so you run it again--without making any changes--hoping for a better outcome. It makes no sense, but we've all done it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the **examples** you provided, it appears your serial numbers will always start with a digit and ends with a letter -- if this isn't true, then refer to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385201/regex-that-will-match-a-combination-of-letters-and-numbers-not-ending-with-km/53385443#comment93646645_53385201) and read up what it's going to take to assist you better.

This pattern should work:

```
/(\d+[a-z0-9]+[a-z](?<!km\b))(?:,|$)/i
```

This requires the following conditions:

- `\d+` start with a minimum of one or more `+` digits `\d`
- `[a-z0-9]+` followed by any alphanumerical character `[a-z0-9]`, one or more times `+`
- `(?<!km\b))(?:,|$)` negative lookahead that asserts the string ends with either a comma `,` or end of string `$`, but not if it comes after the letters km `(?<!km\b)`

This uses a single capturing group `(...)` so you don't include the comma `,` that comes with the entire match

See it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BpTKsC/2)

Comment: thanks, this seems to work, but how can i output the serial number without the coma and the end

Comment: You need to return the submatches - not the entire match. See [What is a capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Comment: `serialNum = string.match(/(\d+\w+(?<!km\b))[,|$]/i).captures` works for Ruby I believe

Comment: if i'm doing something like this: `f = File.open(fileName, "r")
f.each_line do |line| stock = line[/(\d+\w+(?<!km\b))[,|$]/] ` can i use the method `capture` ?

Comment: I'm sorry i just noticed that it is sometimes returning the 'date' in the string

Comment: I fixed it in my last edit @SaraMoufarrej. Sorry I was driving

Comment: Note: `"1a,1_a_b,1akm1".scan /(\d+\w+[a-z](?<!km\b))(?:,|$)/i #=> [["1_a_b"]]`.  `"1_a_b"` incorrectly matches because of what I regard as a curiosity of `\w`, which I rarely use. To match `1a` change `\w+` to `\w*`. You also need to make changes to cause `1akm1` to be matched. Incidentally, coding while operating a moving vehicle is a "distracted driving" offence in most jurisdictions.

Comment: Thanks for the input @CarySwoveland. The reason I decided to go with the `+` quantifier in this case was because I figured a serial number would have to be greater than 2 chrs in length. I could certainly change the `\w` to `[a-z0-9]`, however. And my response of me driving was actually for my lack of a timely response to OP's query (not me coding & driving) xD

Comment: Thank you both for greatly clarifying things

Comment: `"12km,%18131A,22km".scan /(\d+[a-z0-9]+[a-z](?<!km\b))(?:,|$)/i #=> [["18131A"]]`. I'm not sure that is intended.  Sara, do you want that? (btw I returned to this question after many moons because of an upvote of my answer. Upon doing so I noticed my answer was incorrect, so fixed it.)

Answer (score 0):

My understand is that, given a string, you wish to extract all substrings having the following properties:

- the substring is preceded by a comma or begins the string and is followed by a comma or ends the string;
- the substring contains only digits and uppercase letters;
- the substring contains at least one digit;
- the substring contains at least one uppercase letter; and
- the substring cannot end with the string `"km"`.

The test string is the following.

```
str = "65101km,Sedan,Manual,18131A,FWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,camry,SE," +
      "{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010,208A1,28km1"
```

Notice that I've appended the string given in the question with `",208A1,28km1"`.

You can extract the desired substrings using the method [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan) with the following regular expression.

```
r = /
    (?<=\A|,)      # match the beginning of the string or a comma in a positive lookbehind
    [\p{Upper}\d]  # match a digit or uppercase letter in character class
    *              # perform above match zero or more times     
    (?:            # begin a non-capture group
      \d           # match a digit
      \p{Upper}    # match an uppercase letter
      |            # or
      \p{Upper}    # match an uppercase letter
      \d           # match one or more digits
    )              # end non-capture group
    [\p{Upper}\d]  # match a digit or uppercase letter in character class
    *              # perform above match zero or more times     
    (?<!km)        # do not match 'km' (negative lookbehing)
    (?=,|\z)       # match a comma or end of the string (positive lookahead)
    /x             # free-spacing regex definition mode

str.scan(r)
   #=> ["18131A", "208A1"]
```

Alternatively, you could do that in four simpler steps.

```
str.split(',').select do |s| s.match?(/\A\p{Alnum}+\z/) &&
                             s.match?(/\p{Alpha}/) &&
                             s.match?(/\p{Digit}/) &&
                             !s.end_with?("km")
                      end
  #=> ["18131A", "208A1"]
```

Documentation for `\p{}` *constructs* can be found by searching on the same in  [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html). They are similar to *POSIX bracket classes*, which are documented in the same file.

The regular expression is conventionally written (i.e., not free spacing mode) as follows. I've also replaced `\p{Upper}` by its abbreviation, `\p{Lu}`.

```
 r = /(?<=\A|,)[\p{Lu}\d]*(?:\d\p{Lu}|\p{Lu}\d)[\p{Lu}\d]*(?<!km)(?=,|\z)/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with splitting this line into items by the comma and then applying the regular expression to each item:

```
input = "65101km,Sedan,Manual,18131A,FWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota," \
        "camry,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010"
input.split(',').grep(/^(?!.*km)\d+\p{l}+$/)
#⇒ ["18131A"]
```

The above returns an array, so you probably want to handle it somehow (e.g. with `first`.)

The regular expression itself matches all the items, following the pattern `\d+\p{l}+` that do not match `km` ([negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in the beginning.)